# connect then disconnect a unc mapped folder - deny access to explorer

Tags: c#

I have a C# winforms application which needs to access a secured folder on the network, which nobody should have access to.  To achieve this I am executing a command like:

`NET USE \\1.1.1.1\folder /user:1.1.1.1\Username myPassword /persistent:no`

this opens the connection, and the application can now access the files.  When it is finished I am trying to close the connection, using:

`NET USE \\1.1.1.1\folder /delete /y`

this removes it from the list when you type

`net use`

in the command prompt... job done.  maybe not...

the issue I have is, windows is remembering the details, so if i open windows explorer and type in \1.1.1.1\folder it is allowing me to view the files.

This is not a good thing, how can i prevent windows persisting the connection info?

Comment: Can you start `Credential Manager` (search in Windows start menu) and verify that those credential are actually persisted?

Comment: Yes it is  in there

Comment: actually... maybe not...  I deleted it and then ran my application expecting it to re-appear, but it did not re-appear... still can access folder through explorer

Comment: Apparently there's still a kerberos ticket around, even when the credentials are removed. According to [that answer](https://serverfault.com/a/500237/17182), `klist purge` should help.

Comment: thanks, I have tried klist purge and it doesnt appear to help

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry. My next step in your situation would be to try the other answers in the linked serverfault question, to find out whether the login information is stored by Windows or explorer.exe.

Comment: Can you put purge klist as an answer, it appears to work... however there is a delay of maybe 5 to 10 mins before it seems to kick in and prevent connection to the folder??

Comment: In that case, it would be better if you answered your question yourself, including a link to the answer on serverfault and any additional information you can provide (e.g. having to wait for 5-10 min). Personally, I don't need attribution, but the original source on serverfault should be mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239321/discussion-between-andie-and-heinzi).